# How do I automate a key press in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

Is it possible to automate the key press of a key (such as "a" or "<") in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome or Safari (in this order)?
I'd like to automate the key press of "a" for example in Mozilla Firefox for 100 times every `x` seconds. With `x` being a value between 1 second and 10 seconds chosen randomly at every key press. What Applescript could make the trick?

Also, where can I find a list of all codes for each key of the keyboard?

Comment: I don't understand the part "chosen randomly at every key press".

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - before each keypress, a delay with length randomly chosen, of 1 to 10 seconds. So, different each time.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
activate application "Firefox"
repeat 100 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down
    delay (random number from 0.5 to 5)
end repeat
```

More examples:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 123 using {shift down, command down} -- shift-command-left
end
```

```
set old to (path to frontmost application as text)
tell application "Notes"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
delay 1
activate application old
```

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if for example the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notification Center"
    try
        key down option
        delay 0.1
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
    end try
    key up option
end tell
```

See `Events.h` for a list of key codes.

> $ grep '^ *kVK' /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h|tr -d ,|while read x y z;do printf '%d %s %s\n' $z $z ${x#kVK_};done|sort -n
>   0 0x00 ANSI_A
>   1 0x01 ANSI_S
>   2 0x02 ANSI_D
>   3 0x03 ANSI_F
>   4 0x04 ANSI_H
>   5 0x05 ANSI_G
>   6 0x06 ANSI_Z
>   7 0x07 ANSI_X
>   8 0x08 ANSI_C
>   9 0x09 ANSI_V
>   10 0x0A ISO_Section
>   11 0x0B ANSI_B
>   12 0x0C ANSI_Q
>   13 0x0D ANSI_W
>   14 0x0E ANSI_E
>   15 0x0F ANSI_R
>   16 0x10 ANSI_Y
>   17 0x11 ANSI_T
>   18 0x12 ANSI_1
>   19 0x13 ANSI_2
>   20 0x14 ANSI_3
>   21 0x15 ANSI_4
>   22 0x16 ANSI_6
>   23 0x17 ANSI_5
>   24 0x18 ANSI_Equal
>   25 0x19 ANSI_9
>   26 0x1A ANSI_7
>   27 0x1B ANSI_Minus
>   28 0x1C ANSI_8
>   29 0x1D ANSI_0
>   30 0x1E ANSI_RightBracket
>   31 0x1F ANSI_O
>   32 0x20 ANSI_U
>   33 0x21 ANSI_LeftBracket
>   34 0x22 ANSI_I
>   35 0x23 ANSI_P
>   36 0x24 Return
>   37 0x25 ANSI_L
>   38 0x26 ANSI_J
>   39 0x27 ANSI_Quote
>   40 0x28 ANSI_K
>   41 0x29 ANSI_Semicolon
>   42 0x2A ANSI_Backslash
>   43 0x2B ANSI_Comma
>   44 0x2C ANSI_Slash
>   45 0x2D ANSI_N
>   46 0x2E ANSI_M
>   47 0x2F ANSI_Period
>   48 0x30 Tab
>   49 0x31 Space
>   50 0x32 ANSI_Grave
>   51 0x33 Delete
>   53 0x35 Escape
>   55 0x37 Command
>   56 0x38 Shift
>   57 0x39 CapsLock
>   58 0x3A Option
>   59 0x3B Control
>   60 0x3C RightShift
>   61 0x3D RightOption
>   62 0x3E RightControl
>   63 0x3F Function
>   64 0x40 F17
>   65 0x41 ANSI_KeypadDecimal
>   67 0x43 ANSI_KeypadMultiply
>   69 0x45 ANSI_KeypadPlus
>   71 0x47 ANSI_KeypadClear
>   72 0x48 VolumeUp
>   73 0x49 VolumeDown
>   74 0x4A Mute
>   75 0x4B ANSI_KeypadDivide
>   76 0x4C ANSI_KeypadEnter
>   78 0x4E ANSI_KeypadMinus
>   79 0x4F F18
>   80 0x50 F19
>   81 0x51 ANSI_KeypadEquals
>   82 0x52 ANSI_Keypad0
>   83 0x53 ANSI_Keypad1
>   84 0x54 ANSI_Keypad2
>   85 0x55 ANSI_Keypad3
>   86 0x56 ANSI_Keypad4
>   87 0x57 ANSI_Keypad5
>   88 0x58 ANSI_Keypad6
>   89 0x59 ANSI_Keypad7
>   90 0x5A F20
>   91 0x5B ANSI_Keypad8
>   92 0x5C ANSI_Keypad9
>   93 0x5D JIS_Yen
>   94 0x5E JIS_Underscore
>   95 0x5F JIS_KeypadComma
>   96 0x60 F5
>   97 0x61 F6
>   98 0x62 F7
>   99 0x63 F3
>   100 0x64 F8
>   101 0x65 F9
>   102 0x66 JIS_Eisu
>   103 0x67 F11
>   104 0x68 JIS_Kana
>   105 0x69 F13
>   106 0x6A F16
>   107 0x6B F14
>   109 0x6D F10
>   111 0x6F F12
>   113 0x71 F15
>   114 0x72 Help
>   115 0x73 Home
>   116 0x74 PageUp
>   117 0x75 ForwardDelete
>   118 0x76 F4
>   119 0x77 End
>   120 0x78 F2
>   121 0x79 PageDown
>   122 0x7A F1
>   123 0x7B LeftArrow
>   124 0x7C RightArrow
>   125 0x7D DownArrow
>   126 0x7E UpArrow

You can also use AppleScript to click menu items:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    click menu item "Minimize" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    tell menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        click
        click menu item "Open With" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: @daviesgeek So I'm unclear. How would I simulate option, command, H, M being pressed as the same time? I understand key down for the modifiers but how do I intiate the pressing of H and M?

Comment: WARNING: make sure you have all your code in try blocks and safety key ups after the blocks! I got stuck with my `control` key down for a while due to an uncaught exception and was quite frustrated.

Comment: It seems `Events.h` is now found at either `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h` or `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h`.

Comment: This list is awesome. I visit this page so frequently, thanks!

Comment: Is it correct that this only works when a physical keyboard is connected?

Comment: @mVChr I had the same thing happen to me with the `option` key. I had to restart. Is there another way?