# Shortcut used by another action/reboot breaks shortcut

Tags: keyboard, display, macos, bug

I think this is a bug, but perhaps it is a unique problem to me for some reason.  I really like independent display switching in Mavericks, and I set it up in what I guess is a unique way.  I have two monitors with 4 displays each.  Displays 1&5 are activated by the same keyboard shortcut ctrl-1.  All the other displays are activated individually with ctrl-2 through ctrl-7.  This worked really well and I liked it until I rebooted.  Then, it broke.

After rebooting, ctrl-1 still activates display 1, but not display 5.  I figured this was not an intended usage, and so I fixed the keyboard shortcut so that display 5 was activated by a different shortcut.  However, the shortcut for display 5 is completely broken until another reboot, regardless of what key is is set to.

What I want is for this to work the way I want - to support one shortcut key for multiple displays.  I do not expect to get that, unless someone knows of a good utility or plug in that will create that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As I thought about it this morning, I realized I could get this functionality pretty simply - with a macro.  An automator script, as a service, was bound to the ctrl-1.  The spaces were moved to option-1.  The service takes no input, and here is the script:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 18 using {option down}
        key code 23 using {option down}
    end tell
    return "success"
end run
```

A list of key codes can be found here: [How do I automate a key press in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript)

Comment: I had to switch the spaces shortcuts to the awful, control-option-command-N because using just option-N was causing some sort of conflict.