# Perform two keystrokes successively in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want to perform two keystrokes in AppleScript, successively.
The script should perform <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and after that <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the application **Google Chrome**.

Can this be done with AppleScript?

Answer (score 5):

Try using a script like this:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"

    keystroke "j" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 1
    keystroke "w" using command down
    delay 1

end tell
```

Comment: Why `repeat`, even without `n times`? I had to kill applications because of the infinite `repeat`. :(

Comment: Removed `repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to script the System Events application.

There is a good start [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/)

There is a good detailed answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript) with lots of required details.