# Adjusting Brightness, or executing any keypress, on remote computer via ssh

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, ssh, keybindings

What are the options to target specific keys on a remote computer and execute the equivalent of virtually pressing them from the terminal via ssh (what would normally be a user pressing them)?

Example is adjusting the volume:

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 10"
```

I'm not asking for applescript.

Comment: The osascript in your example is using applescript, so, it's not clear to me what you're asking for.  For what it's worth, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript has a good deal of information on how to use applescript to simulate key presses.

Comment: I think you missed the last part of my post. Dang it has been long getting back to this P