# Applescript to emulate key strokes

Tags: applescript, ms-office, microsoft

I want applescript to input into microsoft excel "No, (tab, tab again), Yes". I can't seem to make this work. I would preferably like it to start whenever I press a hotkey or something, but having to swipe over and activate the script should be ok.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Can you add the script you already have?

Comment: @patrix thx for the quick reply, I don't have anything so far, but I have been trying things like "tell application Excel, keystroke "No" to no avail. I am really not talented at things like this so I would be grateful if you could even write a script for me! Thanks, Nick

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a lot of information about how to write Applescript code in general and how to use it to send keystrokes available on the net. [System Events, Key Code and Keystroke](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/keycodes.php) looks kind of interesting in your case and should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @patrix, I got the script working! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.