# Using Automator to take a screen shot from Adobe Digital Editions, Page Down and repeat

Tags: automator, screen-capture

Is there any way to have OS X's Automator.app repeatedly take screen shots of a book in Adobe Digital Editions? So me doing the task involves:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
2. <kbd>space bar</kbd>
3. mouse click
4. <kbd>page down</kbd>
5. repeat…

Can this be automated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You can use with **Script Editor.app** or **Automator.app** for your task. If you choose **Automator.app**, using the **Run AppleScript** action to embed your AppleScript snippets.

## AppleScript: Simulating key presses

Take a look at using AppleScript to automate key presses, [How do I automate a key press in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript) An example from the top answer:

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if for example the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Adobe Digital Editions"
    try
        key down option
        delay 0.1
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
    end try
    key up option
end tell
```

## AppleScript: Capturing screen shots

To take a screen shot, there are numerous approaches. This question is a good starting point, [Take a screen shot and save to desktop with current time as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797998/take-a-screen-shot-and-save-to-desktop-with-current-time-as-the-name):

```
set theDesktop to POSIX path of (path to desktop as string)
set theCurrentDate to current date
set shellCommand to "/usr/sbin/screencapture " & quoted form of (theDesktop & "Screen Shot" & theCurrentDate & ".png")
do shell script shellCommand
```

## AppleScript: Mouse clicks

Simulating the mouse is trickier but likely possible, see [Is there a way to simulate a mouse click anywhere on a screen in Dictate ?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1784654?start=0&tstart=0). AppleScript's GUI scripting is designed to interact with specific elements on the screen.

### Aside: Copyright concerns

Please do not use this process to bypass copyright protection.