# Need my automator script to display the regular shutdown prompt before shutting down

Tags: mac, applescript, automator, script

I'm using the script below to trigger a shutdown but I would like it to give me the normal warning menu with the 60 sec. countdown, I can't figure out the warning menu.

```
tell application "finder" to shut down
```

I don't know what else to put so I get the normal shutdown prompt.

Comment: idk how to do it exactly from Applescript, but if you set a key command to Shut Down... you could just key press that combo from the script. I'm not sure if you can key command the default Power Button or Ctrl/Eject, but you can if you use Keyboard shortcut prefs to assign a new command.

Comment: The thing is that I'm using my Amazon Echo to trigger these commands so I can't use a button press.

Comment: applescript will 'press the buttons' for you `keystroke x using command down` etc - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript - btw, klanomath is *always* worth listening to.. he's just tackling it from another angle right now, but equally if not more valid than my attempt.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate the support, I'll definitely check out that link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the menu item instead:

```
tell application "Finder" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click menu item "Shut Down…" of menu 1 of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

If you use another system language than English use the proper shut down command instead.
At least in OS X 10.11 you have to allow Script Editor/the resulting app to control your computer in System Preferences -> Security -> Privacy -> Accessibility.

---

You have to copy the menu item **exactly** including spaces. E.g. the three dots are not three dots but an ellipsis: <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> -> … (en-US keyboard layout)

Comment: When I tried this it simply brought Finder to the forefront, it didn't activate the menu bar or anything else..  If I could even get it to automate the shortcut buttons that would be fine.

Comment: @KyleHinkebein What's your system version?

Comment: Works perfect!!!  I retyped it from my laptop to my main system and had those dots wrong.. Thanks!!!  Really appreciate it..