# Applescript dialog - return/enter special keys (such as page down)?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am creating an Applescript that shows a dialog where the user should be able to enter either any common character (such as `a`) or any special key (such as page down or ⌘). How can the latter keys/key codes be entered into a regular text field in an Applescript dialog?

Comment: Isn’t this already the case? Just copy and paste or use text replacement.

Comment: @Josh I want the script to know that page down was entered and then act upon that. The visual feedback doesn't really matter.

Comment: @d-b Words or the symbol?

Comment: @Josh The ASCII code. My script is gonna send page down (or enter or A or End) somewhere. That is, repeat the key I just pressed.

Comment: @d-b Ohhhhhhhhhh.  Ok. Try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript

Comment: @d-b Unfortunately I don’t have time to write the code write now (I’m not mobile) but later I will. AppleScript has limited keys that it can use and your script is going to be a giant “if” conglomerate. If you want the full ASCII table your going to have hundreds of if statements (I think 256 but maybe more). There’s not default way to do what you want.

Comment: @d-b Maybe use this https://superuser.com/questions/258825/how-to-type-non-printable-ascii-characters-in-mac-os-x-terminal

Answer (score 3):

As promised:

```
display dialog "Enter your ASCII keycode" default answer ""
set a to the text returned of the result
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character a)
```

[Heres](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) a list of all the possible key codes.

[Common ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236741/using-applescript-to-execute-a-complicated-keystroke):

> You can use any ASCII code, for the arrow keys this will be:
>
> tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 31)
>   --down arrow
>
> tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 30)
>   --up arrow
>
> tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 29)
>   --right arrow
>
> tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 28)
>   --left arrow