# AppleScript: Press “Q” every 1 second after idle for X amount of time in application “Roblox”

Tags: keyboard, applescript, command-line

I am looking for a script that would press "Q" every second when idle for a certain amount of time in an application. I have never coded before and have several issues with code (below) that'd I have no idea how to fix

Here is the code I've tried:

```applescript
repeat 52 times
    repeat 52 times
        delay 0.5
        tell application "Roblox"
            set currentTab to do
            script ("q") in front window 
        end tell 
        delay 0.5 
    end repeat 
end repeat
```

It errors with:

> **error** "The variable do is not defined." number -2753 from "do"

Comment: There are lots of existing questions/answers that address this very topic about key presses in various apps via AppleScript.  What research have you done, what have you tried and what were the results?  What exactly are you attempting to accomplish with this?

Comment: I have done research on the topic but I can't code and several errors occur when I try to run the script I find. I don't want to keep constantly pressing q while watching Netflix, to level up in a game, so I want to find a way to auto press the key.

Comment: *I have done research on the topic but I can't code and several errors occur.*  **You are aware that we can't see over your shoulder, right?**  I'm not trying to be flippant, but please understand...you need to help us help you.

Comment: Ok. One of the scripts I'm trying to use is repeat 52 times
 repeat 52 times
 delay 0.5
 tell application "Roblox"
  set currentTab to do
  script ("q") in front window
 end tell
 delay 0.5
end repeat                           The error that comes up on this is "the variable do         is not defined" It's simple stuff like this that I don't know how to fix. All I need is a simple script that has the letter "q" pressed when I'm idle on the application.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the new details and not post them in comments.  It's impossible to see the structure/syntax of your code.  Comments are for asking clarifying questions/feedback  and there's no way to provide enough context for people to understand what you're posting.

Comment: Please add your current script to the question, how you run it with Roblox and also some details about the error you get.

Comment: The picture of the script in the description is what I am trying to use. The error I get is that "do" is not defined. When I try to define do (variable "do" = execute) it tells me that the variable "variable" is not defined.

Comment: Please do not post unnecessary screen shots when simply copying and pasting is all that necessary.

Comment: The two lines of _code_ `set currentTab to do` and `script ("q") in front window` should be on one line, e.g. `set currentTab to do script ("q") in front window`, **however**, that is an improper use of the `do script` _command_! That said, there are hundreds of examples of how to use **System Events** and the `keystroke`/`key code` _command_ on the **Internet**, I know because I've writen more than a few of them.

Comment: Also, **Ask Different** is not a _code_ writing service! Please take the time to search the **Internet** for `applescript sending keystrokes` and do some reading. There are plenty of working examples out there! The top hit for that search string is: [How do I automate a key press in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have **Roblox**, so I can not help you with anything **Roblox** *application* specific. However, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does in one `repeat` *loop*, as I fail to see the need for two  `repeat` *loops*, it sends a `keystroke` to the frontmost *application*, in this case **Roblox**.

```applescript
repeat 2704 times
    tell application "Roblox" to activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "q"
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. When I first tried it, though I got an error saying System Events doesn't allow Script Editor to send keystrokes. I was able to easily fix it after allowing accessibility in security and privacy settings.