# Safari - AppleScript does not move to the next section of a bookdown online book

Tags: keyboard, applescript, safari, pdf

I am writing a script to print a section of a `bookdown` [online book](https://bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/intro.html) as PDF, then move to the next section, and so on.

The print part works (the key codes are from [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript)):

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    activate
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 35 using command down -- activate print menu item
    end tell
    
    delay 0.5
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 15
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 48 -- press tab 15 times
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 49 -- press space
    end tell
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 2
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 125 -- press down key twice
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36 -- enter
    end tell
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 16
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 125 -- press tab to get to "save"
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36 -- enter to cleck on save
    end tell
    
end tell
```

**Problem**

Now that I have printed the current section and I am back on Safari, I can click manually on the right arrow and move to the next section, but I can't manage to have the script to do that.

I have tried to add the following to the script above:

```
tell application "System Events"
        key code 124 -- right arrow to enter the next page
    end tell
```

Or even to "reopen" Safari, but nothing happens.

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    activate
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 124 -- right arrow to move to the next section
    end tell
    
end tell
```

How can I have AppleScript "turn the page" and move to the next section?

Also, I welcome suggestions to improve the script! I wonder if it would be easy to avoid repeating "tab" 15 times. I have looked at the Accessibility Inspector and found that "PDF" in the print menu corresponds to `NSPopUpButtonCell`. I have tried to use `select NSPopUpButtonCell of its sheet` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can click manually on the right arrow and move to the next section, but I can't manage to have the script to do that.
>
> How can I have AppleScript "turn the page" and move to the next section?

If you are trying to programmatically click the *right-arrow*, as shown in the image below, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can do that:

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell document 1 to ¬
        do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-angle-right')[0].click();"
```

---

**Notes:**

This requires **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be check on the hidden **Develop** menu.

To unhide the hidden **Develop** menu:

- **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** > **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar**

---

[image]

---

**Update to address:**

> Also, I welcome suggestions to improve the script! I wonder if it would be easy to avoid repeating "tab" 15 times.

Here is how I'd use the **JavaScript** from above and coded to avoid using the `key code` and or `keystroke` **System Events**  *commands*, especially **tabbing** around the **UI**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    
    tell application process "Safari"
        
        set frontmost to true
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until (its frontmost = true)
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 20 then return
        end repeat
        
        click menu item "Print…" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "File" of ¬
            menu bar 1
        
        tell its front window
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists menu button "PDF" of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click menu button "PDF" of sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists menu item "Save as PDF" of ¬
                menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click menu item "Save as PDF" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu button "PDF" of ¬
                sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat while (exists sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 100 then return
            end repeat
            
        end tell    
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell document 1 to ¬
        do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-angle-right')[0].click();"
```

---

**Notes:**

Since this type of **AppleScript** *script* is using **UI Scripting**, I have included an *error handling* in the form of a `repeat` *loop* to wait up to two seconds for the target `UI element` to become available to be acted upon for most of the targets, however the last `repeat` *loop* waits longer because it has to wait until the **Save as PDF** to complete. A simple `delay` *command* with an appropriate *value* could be used instead, but with the include delay of a tenth of a second in the `repeat` *loops* it shouldn't have to wait any longer than need be. In other words, I'd only use simple `delay` *command* if I want to slow the *script* down from going through the various events of the **UI**. It's doubtful that it would need to be adjusted, but obviously do so as/if necessary.

If the *timeout* is reached, the *script* aborts at that point without any error message. The single-line `if i ≥ 20 then return` *statements* can be turned into a full `if` *block* and include an error message via the **display dialog**, **display alert**, or **display notification** *command* as wanted.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! But why you don't need `end tell` at the end?

Comment: RE: "But why you don't need end tell at the end?" -- Because it was not written in the form of a `tell` _block statement_ but as a _single-line_. `tell` _statement_.  Note that the `¬` character is a _line continuation_ character and is used for readability (especially when posting _code_ here).

Comment: @Emy, Please see the **Update to address:** _section_ of my updated answer, as it address the first sentence of the last paragraph of your OP.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Emy, I changed the last `repeat` _loop_ as it originally targeted the wrong `UI element`. It's now coded to give time for the **Save to PDF** to complete, as I noticed some of the chapters are quite long and could have been truncated. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you again. I ran into another issue actually but I don't want to take too much of your time and maybe it could be the object of another post. When downloading a book like this one: https://bookdown.org/roy_schumacher/r4ds/ , all the chapters have the same name and the loop gets stuck because of the rewrite. If the chapter have the same name one could just add anumber to the name of the saved file. But again let me know if this should be a different question.

Comment: @Emy, Just an FYI... This would be so much easier to just use `wget` to download the entire book as **HTML** and its _assets_ and then be able to read the whole thing as a _local copy_ in your _web browser_. For example, with the book of this question the only thing I had to change after downloading it with `wget` was the name of one file, i.e., `fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0` in `'../bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/libs/gitbook-2.6.7/css/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0'` to `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` in order to show the icons across the top and the L/R arrows properly.

Comment: **Notes:** `wget` is not a native **macOS** _command line utility_, however, if you use **Homebrew** it can be installed with it. For testing I just did it in a **Linux** _virtual machine_.  The command I used was: `wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --convert-links --wait=10 --limit-rate=20K --domains bookdown.org --no-parent https://bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/` The `--wait` and `--limit-rate` _options_ were set so it wouldn't suck the whole thing down to quickly and get cutoff and blacklisted. The _book_ has 198 items, totaling 19.9 MB and took ~30 min. to download.

Comment: It also did it in the background and allowed me to do other things. I'd highly recommend going this route unless you really want it saved in **PDF** _documents_.  The book linked in your comment is larger than the one of this question so it will take longer to download.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's useful to know. In this cases though, I actually really wanted a PDF because then I can read on a tablet, annotate, and then import to a spaced repetition software.

Comment: @Emy, Okay, I'll look at how the _filename_ can be programmatically handled to avoid being a duplicate in a automated manner and get back to you.  BTW do you use **Homebrew**?

Comment: @Emy, Have a look at: [https://paste.ee/p/GoFER](https://paste.ee/p/GoFER)

Comment: Yes, I have used Homebrew in the past.

Comment: Thank you @user3439894! It works like a charm. I appreciate your help.